# Map Java architecture stack to Microsoft

Tags: java, .net, flash, silverlight, architecture

Coming from Java background, I am now working in a Microsoft shop where we use MS technologies only. Can you please map this architecture stack to the MS world? I am not looking for equivalents to specific layers of the stack, but a proven end-to-end stack that is known to work in the real world:

Thanks!

**Architecture Stack:**
Hibernate
Spring DAO
Spring Declarative transaction management
Domain model POJOs
Spring MVC
BlazeDS
Flex
Flex Interactive data visualization for charting and interactive data analysis

**Cross cutting concerns:**
Security using Acegi+ACL (Data content authorization for user roles)
Testing with Mock Objects
Deployment using Ivy+Ant
Logging with Log4J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Architecture Stack:**

- Hibernate -> NHibernate
- Domain model POJOs -> Domain Model POCOs
- Spring MVC -> ASP.net MVC
- BlazeDS -> RIA Services
- Flex -> Silverlight

For DI, you can just go for spring.net if that is what you are familiar with. Spring and Castle Windsor are probably the most mature, followed closely by StructureMap.

**Cross cutting concerns:**

*Security using Acegi+ACL (Data content authorization for user roles)*

probably have to roll your own.

*Testing with Mock Objects*

.net methods are not virtual by default like java, which dramatically limits what a dynamic proxy (the secret sauce that makes mocking frameworks work in static language) can do. Either Rhino.Mocks or Moq would be the most used that are free, and use the dynamic proxy approach. There is also Typemock Isolator which will mock pretty much anything, but it is 800$/seat.

*Deployment using Ivy+Ant*

Ivy would be Cruise Control if you want free, and TeamCity if you want good (caveat: I am a jetbrains fanboi ;-) Ant would be NAnt or MSBuild (virtually the same thing)

*Logging with Log4J*

Two main choices, either log4net or the Microsoft Enterprise Library Logging Block (love their names) log4net is definately the more lightweight of the two choices, but it depends what you want to do

Answer (score 1):

The following are not so much exact equivalents, but more alternatives used in the .NET world.

Spring MVC -> ASP.NET MVC

Flex -> Silverlight (client side only)

Flex interactive data -> Silverlight charting or ASP.NET Charting

Hibernate -> ADO.NET entity framework.

**EDIT:**

I think the following would be a good starting point (I have left out the things I do not know anything about, such as "declarative transaction management").

SQL Server
[ADO.NET Entity Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa697427%28VS.80%29.aspx)
[.NET RIA Services](http://silverlight.net/getstarted/riaservices/)
[Silverlight](http://silverlight.net/)  (charting components are included in the [Silverlight toolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/Silverlight))

For logging I prefer log4net.

As for reporting and data analysis you might also want to look at SQL Server Analysis Services and Reporting Services.

Also check out [Team Foundation Server](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/teamsystem/default.mspx) for testing, automated builds and deployment.

Comment: I did not frame my question properly, I have edited it now. What I really need is an end-to-end stack that is known to work not just equivalents of each component.

Comment: Ok, I see. I have added some more info now.

Comment: Even with .NET we can use Flex, so Flex-Sliverlight is not a great comparison IMO.

Comment: @Panther24 He clearly states "I am now working in a Microsoft shop where we use MS technologies only". That pretty much excludes Flex, don't you think?

Answer (score 1):

.NET shops tend to be a bit more prescriptive in what is "allowed", so ask your co-workers first before diving right in and just choosing something.

I've used Spring.NET, and the Castle Project and both are pretty solid but not 1:1 feature wise with their Java counterparts. MS shops often tend to stay close to the mothership so are more likely to go with things like The MS Enterprise Library/Unity (solid but verbose), ASP.NET MVC, Silverlight and Entity Framework.

For CI there's TFS (Team Foundation Server, a free version now ships with Visual Studio) but if you want to stick with free software theres CruiseControl.NET, nAnt, nUnit basically take a Java project convert the "j" to and "n" and there's probably a product ;)

Comment: I see your point. But I can convince the team to go outside the mothership, if there are good reasons. Right now, I am learning and do not know for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I know a couple of these have equivalents:

log4j -> [log4net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)

Hibernate -> [NHibernate](https://www.hibernate.org/343.html)

Spring -> [Spring.net](http://www.springframework.net/)

Also, it seems like a POJO isn't really all that java specific (well, I suppose the the J part is :)). I guess a "plain old C# object" could be considered an equivalent ...

Comment: I guess log4net is good if I want to minimize my learning curve. What is considered good in .net world, if I am willing to learn the ".NET way"? Same with other components: is Spring.net really the best that .NET got to offer? Or should I be using something like Windsor Castle?

Comment: @tx10 - log4net, NHibernate and Spring.net are all very mature products in the .NET world.  I wouldn't hesitate to use any of them for a .NET project (and we often do use them)

Answer (score 0):

I found something, does Sharp + Silverlight get me 80% there? Is this considered the current best practice in the .NET world?

http://wiki.sharparchitecture.net/MainPage.ashx

The biggest missing piece I see is Acegi+ACL functionality...

Answer (score 0):

One thing I'd add in, since I don't think it's been mentioned yet, is that Unity is a feasible (and simpler!) alternative to Spring:

http://www.codeplex.com/unity/

Comment: Unity provides support for dependency injection and interception. For everything else, like logging, exception handling and validation, consider using corresponding application blocks from the Enterprise Library. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/entlib)